# Showing API Information with JSX on render with Fetch API React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks, jsx

I am fetching the data with this url:

https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false

and I'm sure my dot notation is correct, but when I try to pass my api information to my child components an error is thrown.

[image]

I think it has something to do with async/await, or when the page is rendered, the data is not yet available to be read. But I'm not sure

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import SmallBox from './SmallBox';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [smallData, setSmallData] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=100&page=1&sparkline=false`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      setSmallData(data)
    })
  })

  return (
    <div className="app">    
      {/* SmallBox - bitcoin */}
      <SmallBox className="bitcoin" title={smallData[0].name}/>
      
      {/* SmallBox - ethereum */}
      <SmallBox className="ethereum" title={smallData[1].name}/>
      
      {/* SmallBox - ripple */}
      <SmallBox className="ripple" title={smallData[2].name}/>
      
      {/* SmallBox - tether */}
      <SmallBox className="tether" title={smallData[3].name}/>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React needs to know what to render at all times. When the component is initially being rendered the external data is not yet set. At this point `smallData[0]` will evaluate to `undefined`. Calling `.name` on `undefined` will result in the error you encounter.

You need to tell React what to render while the data is being fetched, this can be as easy as saying that nothing has to be rendered (returning `null`).

```
// amusing a initial value of null is used for smallData (to simplify the answer)
const [smallData, setSmallData] = useState(null);

// ...

if (!smallData) return null; // <- render nothing

return (
  <div className="app">
    {/* ... */}
  </div>
);
```

You can make things as complex as you want and render a fancy loading component/scene/view.

```
if (!smallData) return <Loading />;
// or
if (!smallData) return renderLoading();

return (
  <div className="app">
    {/* ... */}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

When the component is mounted `smallData[0-3]` don't exist yet because the fetch call hasn't yet executed. React is attempting to render your JSX with the `smallData` variable before it has been properly defined causing the error.

Your JSX template needs to take into account that upon first mount the data will still be loading and not yet ready. So you should display something else until the variable is ready.

First, initialize `smallData` as undefined: `useState({})` > `useState(undefined)`.

Then, update the JSX to display the `SmallBox` elements only when the data is ready and to show a loading label before it's ready.

```
  return (
    <div className="app">
      {!smallData && <div>Loading...</div>}
      {smallData && <div>
        {/* SmallBox - bitcoin */}
        <SmallBox className="bitcoin" title={smallData[0].name}/>
      
        {/* SmallBox - ethereum */}
        <SmallBox className="ethereum" title={smallData[1].name}/>
      
        {/* SmallBox - ripple */}
        <SmallBox className="ripple" title={smallData[2].name}/>
      
        {/* SmallBox - tether */}
        <SmallBox className="tether" title={smallData[3].name}/>
      </div>}
    </div>
  );
```

There are other things to consider as well, such as an error state in case the fetch fails, but this should get you up and running.